# data is not insert into db when using spring jpa and spring test

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-test

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@Transactional
@ContextConfiguration(classes = SimpleConfiguration.class)
public class CustomerSyncRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    CustomerSyncRepository customerSyncRepository;


    @Autowired
    CustomerRepository customerRepository;

    @Autowired
    MemberShipRepository memberShipRepository;

    @Test
    public void collectDataTest() {
        CustomerSync customerSyncOne = new CustomerSync();
        customerSyncOne.setMembershipNumber("1");
        customerSyncRepository.save(customerSyncOne);

        Membership membership = new Membership();
        membership.setName("钻石");
        membership = memberShipRepository.save(membership);

        Customer customerOne = new Customer();
        customerOne.setMembershipNumber("1");
        customerOne.setMembership(membership);
        customerRepository.save(customerOne);

        Customer customerTwo = new Customer();
        customerTwo.setMembershipNumber("2");
        customerTwo.setMembership(membership);
        customerRepository.save(customerTwo);

        customerSyncRepository.collectMissingSyncData();
        assertEquals(2, customerSyncRepository.findAll().size());
    }
}
```

there should be 2 records in db, but it seems that the new record it is never inserted into DB. And when I test it by starting up the application, there are 2 records in db. Is there any configruation I miss in unit test? here is what customerSyncRepository.collectMissingSyncData() do.

```
public interface CustomerSyncRepository  extends JpaRepository<CustomerSync, String> {
    @Modifying
    @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "insert into customer_sync(membershipNumber,membership, cnName, enName, phoneNum, password, email, firstname, lastname, active, otherType, otherNum ) SELECT " +
            "a.membershipNumber, " +
            "b.name, " +
            "a.cnName, " +
            "a.enName, " +
            "a.phoneNum ," +
            "a.password, " +
            "a.email, " +
            "a.firstname, " +
            "a.lastname, " +
            "a.active, " +
            "a.otherType, " +
            "a.otherNum " +
            "FROM " +
            "customer a " +
            "JOIN membership b ON (a.membership_id = b.id) " +
            "WHERE " +
            "a.membershipNumber NOT IN (select membershipNumber from customer_sync) ")
    void collectMissingSyncData();

    List<CustomerSync> findBySync(boolean isSync);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that your saved entities are being stored in the 1st level cache. In other words, they are not yet in the database.

To solve this, just *flush* the state of the 1st level cache into the database.

One way is to inject the `EntityManager` into your test class like this...

```java
@PersistenceContext
EntityManager entityManager;
```

... and then invoke `entityManager.flush()` after each call to `customerRepository.save(..)` (or at least once before the call to `customerSyncRepository.findAll()`).

The other option is simply to invoke the `flush()` method on the repository itself -- for example, if you're using Spring Data JPA repositories.

Comment: That's true. I've already figured it out. But without the need to add the persistenceContext, just enough with customerRepository.flush() Still, thanks.

Comment: Sure. That'll also work. I wasn't thinking about the fact that Spring Data JPA automatically adds a `flush()` method to repositories.